# golang、mongodb，use NewReplaceOneModel,but lost data

Tags: mongodb, go

```golang
updateModels := make([]mongo.WriteModel, 0, len(documents))
    for _, doc := range documents{
        filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "fieldA", Value: fieldA}, primitive.E{Key: "fieldB", Value: fieldB}, primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: doc.ID}}
        replace := bson.D{
            primitive.E{
                Key:   "column",
                Value: doc.Column,
            }, primitive.E{
                Key:   "content",
                Value: doc.Content,
            }}
        model := mongo.NewReplaceOneModel().SetFilter(filter).SetReplacement(replace)
        updateModels = append(updateModels, model)
    }
    if _, err = m.collection.BulkWrite(ctx, updateModels); err != nil {
        return
    }
```

when I use NewReplaceOneModel like this,the doc data will be lost,but if I write like below,it will be ok.

```golang
updateModels := make([]mongo.WriteModel, 0, len(documents))
    for _, doc := range documents{
        filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "fieldA", Value: fieldA}, primitive.E{Key: "fieldB", Value: fieldB}, primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: doc.ID}}
        replace := bson.D{
                        primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: doc.ID},
            primitive.E{Key: "fieldA", Value: fieldA},
            primitive.E{Key: "fieldB", Value: fieldB},
            primitive.E{
                Key:   "column",
                Value: doc.Column,
            }, primitive.E{
                Key:   "content",
                Value: doc.Content,
            }}
        model := mongo.NewReplaceOneModel().SetFilter(filter).SetReplacement(replace)
        updateModels = append(updateModels, model)
    }
    if _, err = m.collection.BulkWrite(ctx, updateModels); err != nil {
        return
    }
```

so I want to know if it's nessary to carry all fields in NewReplaceOneModel,and NewUpdateOneModel may be a better choice? thanks for reading.

I tried to use NewReplaceOneModel in two write ways,and the second reached my goal,I want to know why the first way deleted data,and in this code,using update is better than replace?

Comment: `ReplaceOneModel` as its name says replaces a document. If you don't want to replace but add / update certain fields, use `UpdateOneModel` instead. This works as intended.